# Optical size font and different families font

Tags: xetex, fontsize

I read some post about xelatex and optical size fonts,
but generally the codex is as follows:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Contextuals=NoAlternate}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
Numbers=OldStyle,
Scale=1.1,
SizeFeatures={%
 {Size={-8.4},Font=* Caption},
 {Size={8.41-13.0},Font=*},
 {Size={13.01-19.9},Font=* Subhead},
 {Size={19.91-},Font=* Display}
 }]{Garamond Premier Pro}
```

However, I've got a font (ATF Garamond), whose weights belong to different families:

- Garamond ATF Micro (Regular, Rgular Italic, Bold, ... )
- Garamond ATF Text (Regular, Rgular Italic, Bold, ... )
- Garamond ATF Subhead (Regular, Rgular Italic, Bold, ... )

so I cannot use as in the last line of my example

```
 }]{Garamond Premier Pro}
```

I tried

```
\setmainfont[%
  UprightFont=*,
  ItalicFont=* Italic,
  BoldFont=* Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=* Bold Italic,
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Contextuals=NoAlternate,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  SizeFeatures={%
        {Size={-8.4},Font=* Micro},
        {Size={8.41-13.0},Font=* Text},
       {Size={13.01-19.9},Font=* Subhead}
        },
  Extension=.otf,
  Path= /usr/local/share/fonts/opentype/ATFGaramond/
]{Garamond ATF *}
```

but it produces an error:

```
Invalid filename `[/usr/local/share/fonts/opentype/ATFGaramond/Garamond ATF *.otf]/OT', contains '['

! Package fontspec Error: The font "Garamond ATF *" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.92
```

How is possible to suggest to XeLatex to use correctly the whole families?

thanx

Comment: This is a guess, since that’s one of the (rare) fonts on which I’ve resisted splurging, but have you tried `\setmainfont{Garamond ATF Text}[Contextuals=NoAlternate,Numbers=OldStyle,SizeFeatures={{Size={-8.4},Font=Garamond ATF Micro},{Size={8.41-13.0}},{Size={13.01-19.9},Font=Garamond ATF Subhead}}]`?

Comment: Already aptended and so it complies.But how can I verify it really use all optical fonts? PS Do you prefer this Garamond to Premiere or to EB Garamond?

Comment: Look at the fonts listed in the “Properties” menu of your PDF viewer, or use the command line tool `pdffonts`. Do all the fonts appear (assuming that you have large and small text in your document), or only Garamond ATF Text? And does the greyness of the page look even?  I can’t comment fairly on your last question since I have only two of the three families and so can’t inspect them with equal closeness.

Comment: No, it uses only Text fonts, not the other ones, nor micro nor subhead

Comment: Rats!  Guess I’ll have to buy the font family for purposes of experimentation (sounds like a good excuse…).

Comment: It look like a nice font... maybe I could chamge family names with Fontforge and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change with FontForge all font family name from `GaramondATF Text`, `GaramondATF Subhead` etc to `GaramondATF` to create an unique family. Now I can use correctly XeLaTeX